# How to export associative array to CSV?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

**I need to export the associative array that I have to the .csv file. I can not conclude the way I need.**

i do:

```php
function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "Output.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
            foreach ($line as $row) {
                fputcsv($f, $row, $delimiter);
            }
    }
} 

array_to_csv_download($AllItems);
```

result:

```
"Phone Samsung Galaxy A50 4/64Gb SM-A505F/DS";phone;"LTE, 3G (UMTS), GSM 900, GSM 1800, GSM 1900";Android;"Android 9.0";"Exynos 9610"; ... etc.
```

my array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'Phone Samsung Galaxy A50 4/64Gb SM-A505F/DS',
    'Type' => 'phone',
    'Voice' => 'LTE, 3G (UMTS), GSM 900, GSM 1800, GSM 1900',
    'Platform' => 'Android',
    'OS' => 'Android 9.0',
    'CPU' => 'Exynos 9610',
... etc.
  ),
  1 => 
  array ( ... ),
)
```

how do i get output in.csv like:

```
"Name":"Phone Samsung Galaxy A50 4/64Gb SM-A505F/DS";"Type":phone;"Voice":"LTE, 3G (UMTS), GSM 900, GSM 1800, GSM 1900" ... etc.
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Building your own custom data format will likely fail when you try to parse the data and values contain your custom separator strings. Instead you should use a normal data format like regular csv or json. If you want to use csv, you would only need to include the keys once in a header row instead of adding them to each line.

Comment: Just try this `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('Output.csv'));`